# Copiar uma faixa de células do Excel para um objeto "image" pelo VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso copiar uma faixa de uma planilha do Excel que contém um esquema gráfico feito com bordas em torno de algumas células, com algumas cores de fundo e textos, e visualizar este esquema em um objeto "image" do VBA.

Com o código abaixo a faixa de células que compõe a figura é copiada da planilha atual para outra de nome "Imagem", e é copiada como imagem (como preciso), porém não consegui uma forma de colocá-la no objeto "image", ou ainda, de colá-la diretamente no objeto "image" (assim a planilha "Imagem" seria desnecessária).

```
Range("D19:H25").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

Sheets("Imagem").Activate

Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image: Exemplo de uma faixa de células para transformar em imagem]

Na tentativa de encontrar uma solução, ao fazer manualmente selecionando as células que contêm a imagem, e em "Página Inicial", "Copiar como imagem" (aparência: como mostrada na tela, e formato: Bitmap); ao clicar em propriedades do objeto "image" no campo "Picture" onde está descrito "nenhum" e dar "colar" neste campo, surge a palavra "Bitmap" e no objeto "image" surge a imagem como desejado.

Tentei e pesquisei automatizar este mesmo procedimento no VBA, inclusive fazendo-o por meio de macro e analisando o código, mas evidentemente o código da parte que o desvio é feito para o VBA para "colar" a faixa selecionada na propriedade do objeto (Picture) não é registrado na macro.

Como o esquema gráfico é alterado dinamicamente pelo usuário (via VBA), sempre que o usuário entrar em determinado formulário este objeto "image" precisa apresentar a imagem atual, quantas vezes o usuário desejar refinar esta imagem.

Como resolver isso da forma que preciso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Salvar uma imagem colada em planilha Excel por meio do VBA](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111185/salvar-uma-imagem-colada-em-planilha-excel-por-meio-do-vba)

Comment: A outra pergunta trata de "como salvar a imagem em arquivo", enquanto esta pergunta trata de "como pegar uma imagem e colocá-la em um objeto image do VBA", são dois problemas diferentes para tratamento de uma mesma imagem

Comment: Ok, vi a edição que vc fez. Retirei meu voto de fechar como duplicada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta deletar a imagem anterior (guardando antes a posição em que ela se encontra) e atualizar a nova colada com o mesmo nome e na mesma posição. Eis o código:

```
Set oImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item("Imagem 1")
x = oImage.Left
y = oImage.Top
oImage.Delete

' Seu código
' -------------
Range("e7:E9").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("J19:N25")
' -------------

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Name = "Imagem 1"
Set oImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item("Imagem 1")
oImage.Left = x
oImage.Top = y
```

> IMPORTANTE: Note que nesta resposta eu apenas demonstro como atualizar
>   uma imagem já existente com uma nova imagem gerada a partir dos dados
>   de um range selecionado. [Na sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111185/salvar-uma-imagem-colada-em-planilha-excel-por-meio-do-vba), a minha resposta
>   demonstra como gravar essa imagem (e não o range!) em um arquivo. No
>   final as perguntas não estão duplicadas, mas foi totalmente
>   desnecessário ter duas para resolver o seu problema. Se você tivesse
>   sido mais organizado ao perguntar, teria evitado todas as pequenas
>   confusões e tido a sua resposta mais rapidamente. Fica a dica pro
>   futuro. :)

Comment: Ok, grato, a sua resposta a outra pergunta complementa essa!