# Salvar uma imagem colada em planilha Excel por meio do VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

O código abaixo copia uma faixa de células de uma planilha que é colada como imagem em outra planilha, mas não encontrei uma forma de salvá-la como um arquivo de imagem em uma pasta, ou mesmo selecioná-la para trabalhar com esta imagem pelo VBA.

```
Range("D19:H25").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

Sheets("Imagem").Activate

Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

'a instrução     Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
'coloca a imagem na área de transferência (imagem originada de uma faixa de células selecionadas)

'... como salvar esta imagem em uma pasta a partir da área de transferência?

'... ou como salvá-la se já estiver colada na planilha?

'... como colocar esta imagem em um objeto image, tem como?
```

Se esta imagem colada (que está na área de transferência) pudesse ser salva em uma pasta, mais tarde ela poderia ser lida para um objeto *image* do VBA.

Caso haja como pegar esta imagem da área de transferência e colocar direto em um objeto image, também resolveria, mas de qualquer forma é importante poder salvar esta imagem.

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta pra retirar o complemento... porque ele é desnecessário (você abriu [a sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111145/copiar-uma-faixa-de-c%C3%A9lulas-do-excel-para-um-objeto-image-pelo-vba) por causa disso).

Comment: Ok, estou aprendendo interagir aqui... veja o último comentário que postei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução é a seguinte:

1 - Use o objeto `Shape` para acessar *diretamente* o objeto da imagem. O nome da imagem (no meu exemplo "Imagem 1") é o nome que você pode dar diretamente no Excel, no campo existente próximo à barra de ferramentas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> BTW, a imagem minimalista de exemplo que eu usei [foi tirada
>   daqui](http://randomwallpapers.net/minimalist-star-wars-fun-comic-1920x1080-wallpaper22417.jpg). :)

2 - Então, copie o objeto para a área de transferência. Você pode fazer da forma como já fez, mas usando o objeto pelo nome é mais fácil porque independe do posicionamento dele na planilha.

3 - Finalmente, adicione um objeto de gráfico temporário no Excel, e cole a imagem nele. Esse "truque" é necessário para você utilizar o recurso de salvar como imagem dos objetos gráficos. (*Very clever, Watson!*). A fonte original dessa parte é [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234074/2896619).

Pronto! A sua imagem foi gravada no disco no arquivo solicitado. Eis um exemplo de código:

```
Dim oImage As Shape
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oTemp As ChartObject
Dim oChartArea As Chart

Set oSheet = ActiveSheet
Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.Item("Imagem 1")

oImage.CopyPicture

Set oTemp = oSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, oImage.Width, oImage.Height)
Set oChartArea = oTemp.Chart
oTemp.Activate
With oChartArea
    .ChartArea.Select
    .Paste
    .Export ("C:\Temp\Teste.jpg")
End With
oTemp.Delete
```

Comment: Luiz, excelente, testei manualmente primeiro e funcionou, mas no código falta a declaração das variáveis oTemp e oChartArea, pois uso o Option Explicit e elas são exigidas. Por favor, Como devo declará-las?

Comment: Oi. Editei a resposta para incluir no código as definições que eu havia esquecido. Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor considere aceitá-la.

Comment: Ok, mas a imagem gerada no arquivo foi a do próprio Shape e não a da imagem que foi colada sobre ele. Creio que as linhas que adicionei no código acima para copiar a imagem sobre o Shape devem estar erradas ou faltando algo. Por favor, verifique o meu segundo código.

Comment: A imagem que foi salva no arquivo é a imagem que está no objeto `Shape`. Como VOCÊ MESMO ARGUMENTOU NA SUA OUTRA PERGUNTA (que eu inicialmente julguei duplicada), essa pergunta é só sobre como salvar uma imagem em um arquivo. Lá você deseja saber como atualizar uma imagem com o conteúdo de um range selecionado. Certo?

Comment: São dois problemas com a mesma imagem. Veja, o usuário atualiza a figura no Excel, que, primeiro, eu preciso copiar e colar como imagem (isto está ok), segundo preciso colocar esta imagem num objeto image para apresentar no sistema, sem ser na planilha, e ao mesmo tempo, preciso salvar esta imagem em uma pasta, pois cada projeto terá imagens diferentes. É isso.

Comment: Entendi. Bom, agora tá tudo certo então. :)

Comment: Oi Luiz, na verdade não, pois testei as soluções apresentadas e não consegui salvar a imagem copiada sobre o Shape para o arquivo (salvou a imagem do próprio Shape) e colocar a imagem copiada dentro de um objeto image. Evoluímos, mas ainda preciso dessas soluções.

Comment: Cara, desculpe, mas eu não entendi a sua dificuldade. A imagem não está sobre um shape. Ela **é** um shape. O exemplo que eu fiz aqui funciona exatamente como ilustrado (ele salva o desenho do stormtrooper de óculos no arquivo).

Comment: Desculpe eu pela minha dificuldade e agradeço teu empenho em me ajudar. É exatamente isso que eu não entendi. Eu criei um Shape "retângulo" no próprio Excel para poder dar o nome ao Shape como me indicou (dar o nome manualmente). Acredito que ai pode estar o meu erro. Quero pegar a imagem que eu copiei de uma faixa de células e que está na área de transferência para colar ou gerar este Shape e poder salvá-la como indicou. Pelo que está dizendo, você consegue gerar a imagem como sendo o próprio Shape, o que resolveria meu problema.

Comment: Ah, ok. Não era pra fazer isso. Pegue uma imagem qualquer e cole-a no Excel. Ela vai ser imediatamente um Shape. Dai dê o nome a ela. Os códigos dessa e da outra pergunta trabalham diretamente com a imagem. É que no Excel, uma imagem é também um Shape. :)

Comment: Ok. Agora entendi, funcionou!!! Muito obrigado, resolveu um problemão!

Comment: Veja o que descobri: substituindo no código "oImage.CopyPicture" por  "oImage.Select" a imagem é atualizada automaticamente, acho que valeria a pena você agregar isto à usa resposta.

Comment: O que você "descobriu" foi uma coincidência. Como o código usa o comando `.Paste` como um "truque" pra gravar a imagem, provavelmente você deu sorte de que a imagem ainda estava no clipboard e por isso deu certo. Teste executando isso após ter copiado um texto qualquer pro clipboard e vc vai ver que ele vai salvar lixo. O comando `.Select` apenas seleciona o objeto da imagem, e não faz a cópia pro clipboard (que você **precisa** fazer!).

Comment: Você está certo, com o comando oImage.CopyPicture a imagem não é atualizada,mas tirando este comando (sem por o outro também) é o suficiente para atualizar a imagem no ato da cópia, não entendi a lógica disso funcionar assim no VBA, pois o comando que você usou faz todo o sentido.